# pip install notebook ----shown alreaddy satisfied but when command jupyter notebook-('jupyter' is not recognized file)

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

```
pip install jupyterlab
Requirement already satisfied: jupyterlab in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (3.0.15)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-core in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from jupyterlab) (4.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2>=2.1 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from jupyterlab) (2.11.3)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from jupyterlab) (7.21.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tornado>=6.1.0 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from jupyterlab) (6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from jupyterlab) (20.9)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-server~=1.4 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from jupyterlab) (1.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: nbclassic~=0.2 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from jupyterlab) (0.2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyterlab-server~=2.3 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from jupyterlab) (2.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from jinja2>=2.1->jupyterlab) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: argon2-cffi in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from jupyter-server~=1.4->jupyterlab) (20.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyzmq>=17 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from jupyter-server~=1.4->jupyterlab) (22.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-client>=6.1.1 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from jupyter-server~=1.4->jupyterlab) (6.1.12)
Requirement already satisfied: nbformat in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from jupyter-server~=1.4->jupyterlab) (5.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: nbconvert in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from jupyter-server~=1.4->jupyterlab) (6.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: prometheus-client in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from jupyter-server~=1.4->jupyterlab) (0.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Send2Trash in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from jupyter-server~=1.4->jupyterlab) (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: terminado>=0.8.3 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from jupyter-server~=1.4->jupyterlab) (0.9.2)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython-genutils in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from jupyter-server~=1.4->jupyterlab) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: traitlets>=4.2.1 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from jupyter-server~=1.4->jupyterlab) (5.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: anyio<4,>=3.0.1 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from jupyter-server~=1.4->jupyterlab) (3.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: websocket-client in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from jupyter-server~=1.4->jupyterlab) (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.8 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from anyio<4,>=3.0.1->jupyter-server~=1.4->jupyterlab) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: sniffio>=1.1 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from anyio<4,>=3.0.1->jupyter-server~=1.4->jupyterlab) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from jupyter-client>=6.1.1->jupyter-server~=1.4->jupyterlab) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32>=1.0 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from jupyter-core->jupyterlab) (300)
Requirement already satisfied: babel in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from jupyterlab-server~=2.3->jupyterlab) (2.9.1)
Requirement already satisfied: json5 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from jupyterlab-server~=2.3->jupyterlab) (0.9.5)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from jupyterlab-server~=2.3->jupyterlab) (2.25.1)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema>=3.0.1 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from jupyterlab-server~=2.3->jupyterlab) (3.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyrsistent>=0.14.0 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from jsonschema>=3.0.1->jupyterlab-server~=2.3->jupyterlab) (0.17.3)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\program files\windowsapps\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages (from jsonschema>=3.0.1->jupyterlab-server~=2.3->jupyterlab) (56.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.11.0 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from jsonschema>=3.0.1->jupyterlab-server~=2.3->jupyterlab) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.4.0 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from jsonschema>=3.0.1->jupyterlab-server~=2.3->jupyterlab) (20.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: notebook<7 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from nbclassic~=0.2->jupyterlab) (6.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ipykernel in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from notebook<7->nbclassic~=0.2->jupyterlab) (5.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pywinpty>=0.5 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from terminado>=0.8.3->jupyter-server~=1.4->jupyterlab) (0.5.7)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.0.0 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from argon2-cffi->jupyter-server~=1.4->jupyterlab) (1.14.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from cffi>=1.0.0->argon2-cffi->jupyter-server~=1.4->jupyterlab) (2.20)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2015.7 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from babel->jupyterlab-server~=2.3->jupyterlab) (2021.1)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from ipython->jupyterlab) (0.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: backcall in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from ipython->jupyterlab) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pickleshare in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from ipython->jupyterlab) (0.7.5)
Requirement already satisfied: jedi>=0.16 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from ipython->jupyterlab) (0.18.0)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from ipython->jupyterlab) (4.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from ipython->jupyterlab) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: prompt-toolkit!=3.0.0,!=3.0.1,<3.1.0,>=2.0.0 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from ipython->jupyterlab) (3.0.16)
Requirement already satisfied: parso<0.9.0,>=0.8.0 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from jedi>=0.16->ipython->jupyterlab) (0.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: wcwidth in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from prompt-toolkit!=3.0.0,!=3.0.1,<3.1.0,>=2.0.0->ipython->jupyterlab) (0.2.5)
Requirement already satisfied: bleach in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter-server~=1.4->jupyterlab) (3.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: mistune<2,>=0.8.1 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter-server~=1.4->jupyterlab) (0.8.4)
Requirement already satisfied: defusedxml in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter-server~=1.4->jupyterlab) (0.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: nbclient<0.6.0,>=0.5.0 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter-server~=1.4->jupyterlab) (0.5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: entrypoints>=0.2.2 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter-server~=1.4->jupyterlab) (0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: testpath in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter-server~=1.4->jupyterlab) (0.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyterlab-pygments in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter-server~=1.4->jupyterlab) (0.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pandocfilters>=1.4.1 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter-server~=1.4->jupyterlab) (1.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: async-generator in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from nbclient<0.6.0,>=0.5.0->nbconvert->jupyter-server~=1.4->jupyterlab) (1.10)
Requirement already satisfied: nest-asyncio in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from nbclient<0.6.0,>=0.5.0->nbconvert->jupyter-server~=1.4->jupyterlab) (1.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: webencodings in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from bleach->nbconvert->jupyter-server~=1.4->jupyterlab) (0.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.0.2 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from packaging->jupyterlab) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from requests->jupyterlab-server~=2.3->jupyterlab) (2020.12.5)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from requests->jupyterlab-server~=2.3->jupyterlab) (1.26.4)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<5,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from requests->jupyterlab-server~=2.3->jupyterlab) (4.0.0)
```

```
C:\Users\HP>jupyter notebook
'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

```
C:\Users\HP>jupyter-lab
'jupyter-lab' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

```
C:\Users\HP>pip install notebook
Requirement already satisfied: notebook in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (6.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: nbconvert in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from notebook) (6.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-core>=4.6.1 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from notebook) (4.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Send2Trash>=1.5.0 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from notebook) (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tornado>=6.1 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from notebook) (6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: ipykernel in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from notebook) (5.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from notebook) (2.11.3)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython-genutils in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from notebook) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: terminado>=0.8.3 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from notebook) (0.9.2)
Requirement already satisfied: prometheus-client in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from notebook) (0.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: traitlets>=4.2.1 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from notebook) (5.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: nbformat in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from notebook) (5.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-client>=5.3.4 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from notebook) (6.1.12)
Requirement already satisfied: pyzmq>=17 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from notebook) (22.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: argon2-cffi in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from notebook) (20.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from jupyter-client>=5.3.4->notebook) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32>=1.0 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from jupyter-core>=4.6.1->notebook) (300)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.1->jupyter-client>=5.3.4->notebook) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pywinpty>=0.5 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from terminado>=0.8.3->notebook) (0.5.7)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.0.0 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from argon2-cffi->notebook) (1.14.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from cffi>=1.0.0->argon2-cffi->notebook) (2.20)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython>=5.0.0 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from ipykernel->notebook) (7.21.0)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel->notebook) (0.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pickleshare in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel->notebook) (0.7.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel->notebook) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=18.5 in c:\program files\windowsapps\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel->notebook) (56.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: backcall in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel->notebook) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel->notebook) (4.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: jedi>=0.16 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel->notebook) (0.18.0)
Requirement already satisfied: prompt-toolkit!=3.0.0,!=3.0.1,<3.1.0,>=2.0.0 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel->notebook) (3.0.16)
Requirement already satisfied: parso<0.9.0,>=0.8.0 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from jedi>=0.16->ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel->notebook) (0.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: wcwidth in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from prompt-toolkit!=3.0.0,!=3.0.1,<3.1.0,>=2.0.0->ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel->notebook) (0.2.5)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from jinja2->notebook) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: nbclient<0.6.0,>=0.5.0 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from nbconvert->notebook) (0.5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: entrypoints>=0.2.2 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from nbconvert->notebook) (0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: defusedxml in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from nbconvert->notebook) (0.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pandocfilters>=1.4.1 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from nbconvert->notebook) (1.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: bleach in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from nbconvert->notebook) (3.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: mistune<2,>=0.8.1 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from nbconvert->notebook) (0.8.4)
Requirement already satisfied: testpath in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from nbconvert->notebook) (0.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyterlab-pygments in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from nbconvert->notebook) (0.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: nest-asyncio in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from nbclient<0.6.0,>=0.5.0->nbconvert->notebook) (1.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: async-generator in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from nbclient<0.6.0,>=0.5.0->nbconvert->notebook) (1.10)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from nbformat->notebook) (3.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyrsistent>=0.14.0 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4->nbformat->notebook) (0.17.3)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.4.0 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4->nbformat->notebook) (20.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from bleach->nbconvert->notebook) (20.9)
Requirement already satisfied: webencodings in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from bleach->nbconvert->notebook) (0.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.0.2 in c:\users\hp\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from packaging->bleach->nbconvert->notebook) (2.4.7)
```

```
C:\Users\HP>jupyter notebook
'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: You need to edit your PATH to include the installed jupyter binary

Answer (score 0):

try
`pip install jupyter`

this command worked with me ;)

then should work when you write

`jupyter notebook`

Comment: tried and still not working it shows already satisfied

Answer (score 0):

My jupyter notebook does not work after installing and running it in the terminal.

To fix it I **only** used `pip install simplejson`.
Then I start it with `jupyter notebook` and it works!

You might have to use `pip uninstall simplejson` before `pip install simplejson`.